# Libraries for Playing/Seeking OGG files 

Tags: c#, java, ogg

I have been tasked to create a GUI program that is to work with Ogg files. The main requirements are as follows:

1. The program must run for both Windows and Mac OS X users.

   - It is best to not force Wine, Boot Camp, etc for non Windows users.
2. The library that I use, if any, must play **and** seek Ogg files successfully.
3. The primarily languages allowed are Java or C# (hence the tags). Python is considered ineligible. Other languages with better libraries can be discussed on a case by case basis.
4. The program I am tasked to create is meant to be free. However, its purpose is to enhance a commercial product.

As far as what I have tried to find so far and none fit requirements completely:

- [JOrbis](http://www.jcraft.com/jorbis/) is a Java Ogg Vorbis decoder, but does not have great documentation or seek-ability for the test files I have.
- [DragonOGG](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dragonogg/) works with C# (not necessarily forbidden due to Mono), but is on par wit JOrbis in terms of being bad for seeking.
- [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/) actually works for playing and seeking Ogg files correctly, but its licensing terms prevent me from using it.
- [fmod](http://fmod.net/index.html) has not been tried, but has a similar licensing issue as BASS.

With this in mind, I'm willing to bet that there are other libraries out there. I'm a bit burned out, however.

What libraries, if any, do you guys recommend?

Comment: please check my edit of your question (mainly removing "libraries suck" from title).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need a decoder that can also seek, try *[NVorbis](http://nvorbis.codeplex.com/)*.  It is written in C# and attempts to support sample-accurate seeking (it appears to work for me, but I've not done a rigorous test to make sure).

The license is **MS-Pl**, so I think you should be able to use it in your project.

**Disclaimer**: I am the primary developer & coordinator for *NVorbis*.

Comment: The licensing scheme seems fair. I think I also found a way to convert doubles to longs for the Position argument. The only thing left that I need to do is prove that I'm seeking to the right position by getting a timer going at the same time. This may take a little time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if the api is still for free but **FMOD** should be your friend.
There are some C# Wrapper out there. Many Platforms are supported.
Give it a try.

Edit:
Sorry, my bad, there are of course csharp Samples included in the Development download.
http://fmod.net/fmod-downloads.html
Look for FMODex Downloads > Development

Comment: I am afraid I have to skip FMOD as well. [Their licensing scheme](http://fmod.net/fmod-sales.html) does not look great for me either. I'll edit the original post.